# opencl debugger settings in vs 2010

Tags: opencl

I just want to ask a very simple question: where can I find the opencl debugger configuration dialog in visual studio 2010. There is no code builder tab in vs2010 as well as I could not find it under the tools tab. I just want to enable opencl debugger, play around work item values and debug my kernel code.

Any help would be appreciated?

p.s: everything has worked fine from installation to code building to application execution. Just want to know why the opencl sdk debugger plug-in does not appear anywhere in vs2010.

thanks,

Mork.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Visual Studio debugger to debug OpenCL kernels.

Update: Per the informative comment from @Omair Khan, under certain conditions (source in file) you can debug CPU kernels in Visual Studio when using the Intel CPU driver. However, you cannot use the Visual Studio debugger for GPU kernels.

Comment: well that's not true. You can certainly do that with the opencl debugger plug-in that comes with the intel opencl sdk (https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/opencl/user-guide/Debugging_Your_OpenCL_Kernel_with_Intel_SDK_for_OpenCL_Debugger.htm)